# Laravel Aws\Kinesis\KinesisClient not found

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services

I would like to use `Aws\Kinesis\KinesisClient` on my Laravel project but unfortunately, when I install package using

```
composer require aws/aws-sdk-php
```

and try to use

```
use Aws\Kinesis\KinesisClient;
```

I got

```
Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: Class 'Aws\Kinesis\KinesisClient not found.
```

Please guide me how to use `KinesisClient` on laravel project.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php#create-an-amazon-s3-client) says that; you need to include `vendor/autoload.php` before using it.

```
<?php
// Require the Composer autoloader.
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Aws\S3\S3Client;
```

If you don't want to `require` on every class you use, then maybe you may check this [repository](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php-laravel) to load with service provider. (more laravel way)

> This is a simple Laravel service provider for making it easy to include the official AWS SDK for PHP in your Laravel and Lumen applications.